# Given list of Employees, find employees that has salary between given range without iterating over entire list

Tags: java, performance

Given list of employees:

```
    [Employee{employeeNumber='1', name='A', age=21, department='CS', salary=2000},
 Employee{employeeNumber='2', name='A', age=21, department='CS', salary=5000}, 
 Employee{employeeNumber='3', name='A', age=21, department='CI', salary=3000}, 
 Employee{employeeNumber='4', name='A', age=21, department='CI', salary=4000}, 
 Employee{employeeNumber='5', name='A', age=21, department='CS', salary=6000}, 
 Employee{employeeNumber='6', name='A', age=21, department='CI', salary=7000}]

private String employeeNumber;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String department;
    private BigDecimal salary;
```

I am trying to find employees with given range salaries.
For Example: if given range is 3000 - 5000 then function should return employees(3, 4, 2).

Now I could do this multiple ways:
1) using for loop/iteraton
2) using Stream API

However, if given millions of records then using iteration doesn't make sense.

Any ideas on how it could be done (maybe comparator) without using iterations or stream API??

Comment: If the list isn't sorted w.r.t salaries, there is no option but to iterate through the entire list

Comment: If you want to do this just once, you have no option but to iterate the entire list. If you want to do this more than once, you have to iterate the entire list at least once; but in that iteration you can build a structure which makes future lookups faster (e.g. sorting, binning etc).

Comment: A comparator would end up using iteration. You either need the list to be sorted by salary or, better still, maintain a second data structure (or even an in-memory SQL database) that provides references to the employee objects, that is ordered by salary.

Comment: For millions of records use a database with a WHERE clause in the query to filter the selected records.

Comment: "However, if given millions of records then using iteration doesn't make sense." - Why not?

Comment: It much depends on the source of your data, if your source is already a List, then looping over it is possibly the best way, if your source is something else (like a recordset) , you can still use a loop, you just don't build a list first.
If your data is already a stream, then you can use reducing operations.

Comment: assuming the list is sorted by salary. what would be the option? @mettleap

Comment: So let's say the list is sorted in ascending order ... do a binary search to find the first employee having salary less than the range_lower_bound and similarly find the first employee having salary more than range_upper_bound ... Once you have done this in O(log(N)) time, return all employees in between as the answer

Comment: Thank you all! @mettleap binarysearch would do!